# REST API modeling

Tags: api, rest

I got two models, a Notebook and a Note one.

I got two routes than can achieve the same (post a note for a specific notebook)

`POST /api/note` , need to pass notebook ref (id) in the submited datas

`POST /api/notebook/[ID]/note` , with now now only the note data

Note that I don't need "notes that would not be attached to a notebook".

I read many docs about REST APIs, but I can figured out what's the "best" way.

Does anybody here have some good docs for me?

Comment: 1) Can a Note exist without a Notebook? 2) Can a Note exist in more than one Notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that **a note can only exist in one and only one notebook**. Then a note is a *subresoure* of a notebook. A note is identifed by

```
/api/notebook/{notebookId}/note/{noteId}
```

A new note inside a notebook is created by

```
POST /api/notebook/1234/note
Content-Type: application/json

{
  // details of the note without reference to the notebook
}
```

The server returns

```
201 Created
Location: /api/notebook/1234/note/B175A7F2-1434-11E5-AFD4-82854B860EDE
```

with `B175A7F2-1434-11E5-AFD4-82854B860EDE` being a unique ID assigned to the new note by the server.

Comment: It should be `notebooks` and `notes` since these parts indicate a collection of resources.